# Vuetify rounded autocomplete menu width

Tags: autocomplete, menu, width, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify autocomplete component which looks just fine when the autocomplete is not rounded. When I make it rounded it looks like this. Is there an easy way to make it look a bit nicer and have the menu be a bit more narrow or something like that?

[image]

Comment: I also have the same issue. Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like Vuetify has a fix for this yet, but I did this which gets me closer to what I'd like it to look like. There is most likely a better solution to this, but for now, this worked for my project.

This may not work for you, but it's worth a shot as a temporary solution.

```
.v-autocomplete__content.v-menu__content {
   transform-origin: center top !important;
   transform: scale(0.97) !important;
}
```

Brings in the edges so it doesn't look terrible on the rounded corners.

[image]

Comment: This works pretty well as a temporary solution, thanks.